# I want a link to change a field on a form

Tags: php, html

Basically this is what I want:

Person that comes to my website clicks link

```
<a href="/form.html">Clicking here will pre-select Option 1</a>
<a href="/form.html">Clicking this one will pre-select Option 2</a>
```

Then the link that was clicked will determine what option will be pre-selected in the form.

```
<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

I was thinking that this could be done with PHP $_GET maybe? I'm really not sure.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indeed $_GET, but you need to change the form file suffix to .php

```
<a href="/form.php/?option=1">Clicking here will pre-select Option 1</a>
<a href="/form.php/?option=2">Clicking this one will pre-select Option 2</a>
```

form.php:

```
<?php if (!isset($_GET['option']) {
    //redirect
     }
 ?>
<select>
<option <?php if ($_GET['option']==1) echo "selected"; ?> >Option 1</option>
<option <?php if ($_GET['option']==2) echo "selected"; ?>>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your option determination does not depend on server side data then this can be done on client side with JavaScript as well. All you need to do is to extract query string value from the URL and set the option selected based on extracted value.